# vue + quill - icons are shown as text (caused by file-loader)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quill

**Updated to showcase replicated problem**

SVGs are being imported through file-loader and I am unable to use `raw-loader` or `html-loader`: https://codesandbox.io/s/llr8x89j47

[image]

It's currently displaying it as "img/redo.01da1a6f.svg" instead of

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 18 18"> <polygon class="ql-fill ql-stroke" points="12 10 14 12 16 10 12 10"></polygon> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M9.91,13.91A4.6,4.6,0,0,1,9,14a5,5,0,1,1,5-5"></path> </svg>
```

I am unable to resolve this issue with the current most promising answer.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @Chris I'm thinking that it might be related to svg-loader. I am checking that out now.

Comment: When I opened your codesandbox I see 2 rotate icons in there

Comment: @flppv yeah I can't recreate the problem in codesandbox, is a vue-cli3 thing I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was pretty simple, just override any rules using `!!loader!`

i.e.

```
import UndoIcon from "!!raw-loader!quill/assets/icons/undo.svg"
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because quill expects images to be raw svg strings.
To fix it add `raw-loader` or `html-loader` and modify your `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // Exclude quill assets from file-loader
    config.module
      .rule("svg")
        .exclude
          .add(/node_modules[\\/]quill/)
          .end()

    // Add rule to load quill svg images as raw strings
    config.module
      .rule('quill-svg')
        .include
          .add(/node_modules[\\/]quill/)
          .end()
        .test(/\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/)
        .use('raw-loader')
          .loader('raw-loader')
  }
};
```

You can add additional `include` rules if you have custom svg files you want to use with quill.

Comment: I feel like this should be the right answer, but file-loader is still occuring. I've also got `vue-cli-plugin-svg` installed, so maybe that's still interfering somehow?

Comment: It should work with `vue-cli-plugin-svg` too. Are you using linux? I have updated answer with fixed regex to work on linux

Answer (score 0):

Add **"svg-inline-loader"**:

```
yarn add svg-inline-loader
```

Then in your `vue.config.js` (create this file at the project root if it doesn't exist), copy/paste this rule:

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('svg')
      .test(() => false)
      .use('file-loader')
  }
}
```

It should work.

---

**[Original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49941568/9541423)**

Comment: I need it to use HTML because `svg-inline-loader` turns it into a javascript function, which is great if you want to use it as a component, but doesn't work for my situation.